# i cannot insert rows into my psycopg2 script in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

I am trying to build a money spending monitor and am starting with db.
i have a script for building the table:

```
def create_table(name):
    conn = db.connect(dbname='Money_Tracker' ,user="",password="",host="",port="")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {name}(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,F_Name VARCHAR, L_Name VARCHAR, Expense INT, Category VARCHAR  )")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

and created a table

```
create_table("money_spent")
```

secondly i built a function in order to insert data into the table:

```
def add_money_spent(Firstname, Lastname, Amount, Cat):
    conn = db.connect(dbname='Money_Tracker' ,user="",password="",host="",port="")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO money_spent VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)",(Firstname,Lastname,Amount,Cat))
    conn.close()
```

and am tring to use it like this:

```
add_money_spent("Michael","Ben-Haym",15,"Cofee")
```

when i run the code i get the error **sycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type integer: "Cofee"
LINE 1: ... INTO money_spent VALUES(15, 'Michael', 'Ben-Haym', 'Cofee')**

it seems the code thinks cofee should be an integer even though i specified in the table that categories should be varchar
can someone please explain to me how i can fix this? 
thanks :)

Comment: Can you try instead: `cur.execute("INSERT INTO money_spent (F_name, L_Name, Expense, Category) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)",(Firstname,Lastname,Amount,Cat))`?

Comment: now i don't get an error but it also doesn't get into the db, it stays empty

Comment: Ok, do `conn.commit()` before you close the connection.

Comment: omg i cant belive i forgot the commit i love you thanks it works now

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the column order is random. So you must specify it:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO money_spent (F_name, L_Name, Expense, Category) 
               VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s);""",(Firstname,Lastname,Amount,Cat))
```

Then please make sure to commit your changes with:

```
conn.commit()
```

Before you close the connection.